# Plotting multiple graphs in a single window by using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to make matlab record live data from muse headset and I'm successful to plot accelerometer data and voltage v/s time data in a single window. if I try to add new graph for the same window, then the new graph will overlap with the existing code.

Here is a part of code which deals with plotting of graphs.

```
subplot(2,1,1);
         time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
         h1 = plot(time,eegBuffer);
         legend(eegName, 'Location','EastOutside');
         xlabel('Time (s)')
         ylabel('Voltage (uV)')        

         subplot(2,1,2);
         time = 0:1/fsa:secBuffer-1/fsa;
         h2= plot(time,accBuffer);
         xlabel('Time (s)')
         ylabel('Acceleration (mG)')
         legend(h2, accName, 'Location','EastOutside');

         subplot(2,1,3);
         final = eegBuffer*5;
         h3 = plot(final,eegBuffer);
         xlabel('final')
         ylabel('eegbuffer')
         %legend(h2, accName, 'Location','EastOutside');

         plot1 = false;

        else
         cell1 = (num2cell(eegBuffer,1))';
         set(h1,{'ydata'},cell1);
         cell2 = (num2cell(accBuffer,1))';
         set(h2,{'ydata'},cell2);
         cell3 = (num2cell(final,1))'; 
         set(h3,{'ydata'},cell3);
```

And here is the screen shot:
[image: screen shot]

Comment: you want to have the same window (figure) and just another plot? if so should it be part of an existing plot (check out `hold on`) or just change the number of subplots accordingly. E.g. change all subplots to `subplot(3,1,k)` results in 3 different canvas. (over each other) if you change the second entry you get them side to side. So e.g. `subplot(2,2,k)` would be 4 canvas arranged as 2x2

Comment: Great! I used subplot(3,1,k) in all subplots and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `subplot(2,1,X)`. If you read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html), the first two numbers are rows and colums of the "plot matrix", therefore, you are defining a plot matrix of 2x1=2 subplots.

If you want to plot 3 things you should change the subplot lines to:

```
subplot(2,2,1)  

subplot(2,2,2)

subplot(2,2,3)  % or subplot(2,2,3:4) for even more fancy ploting
```

Comment: Thank you. I got 3 graphs in a single window now :)

Comment: +1 for `subplot(2,2,3:4)`, I didn't know about that!

Comment: @LuisMendo aaah Matlab and his nice plots, this small things make me love Matlab so much!

Comment: @AnderBiguri And [improvements](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update) seem to be on the way!

Comment: @LuisMendo O.o Amazing! no more need of export_fig ! It really looks nice!